# Why does print run only after executing while loop is done in Jython and not during the execution of the while loop

Tags: python, jython, jython-2.7

I already tried using sys.stdout.write(output) sys.stdout.flush(), The Script is running in Jython using JMX, in Python its ok

Just print after the program is done and not when the infinite while is executing

```
while True:
  for enlace in enlaces:
    try:
     print( monitor.status("proc", "stat" + enlace))
     print("----------------------------------------------------")
    except Error, e:
      print ("Script Failed, " + e.value )

  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: would you mind sharing the output  ?

Comment: How does the loop exit?

Comment: Try using `print(..., flush=True)`

Comment: 1)  the output I was trying to print, any string even "----"

Comment: 2) the loop exit when I put a break when Im testing, in this case will not exit

Comment: 3) this version of Python throws an error when I put (flush=True)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.